# OpenApi 3 with Spring Boot 3 - how to declare a redirect from "/" to "/swagger-ui/index.html"?

Tags: spring-boot, redirect, openapi, springdoc

We are migrating the API documentation from a `swagger.yaml` file to annotations in the controllers.

The main reason for this work is that any changes to the API require work in more than one place. The `.yaml` file needs to be validated, the interface re-generated and implemented. There is a chance that changes to the code may not be reflected in the `.yaml` file.

While it is working fine using **`io.swagger.v3.(...)`**, if I explicitly enter the full URL `https://localhost:8443/swagger-ui/index.html` it will resolve the OpenAPI page.

But, if I enter `https://localhost:8443` the following method is hit as it prints out `https://localhost:8443/swagger-ui/index.html` but does not redirect to that page.

```
@RestController
public class Controller {    

    @GetMapping(value = "")
    public String index() {
        var baseUrl = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().build().toUriString();

        String redirect = String.format("redirect:%s/swagger-ui/index.html", baseUrl);
        System.out.println(redirect);
        return redirect;
    }
    // other methods
}
```

Using the method above shows the "/" endpoint in the OpenAPI page, which I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access swagger-ui directly from the application root path, instead of the endpoint for redirection, add the following property to `application.properties`:

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.use-root-path=true
```